# Sort dataframe based on a specific column after GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas

I initially had a dataframe called df. I grouped my dataframe based on specific criteria that I had in mind using the following command.

```
df= df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.strftime('%B'), 'Project','Name'])['Hours'].sum()
```

As a result of this I got the following data frame.

```
**Date**   **Project**                     **Name**                          **Hours**
September  Project 1                          x                                1.00
                                              x                                3.00
           Project 2                          a                                16.00
                                              z                                4.00
           Project 3                          y                                1.00
June       Project 1                          x                                1.00
                                              x                                45.00
                                              y                                6.00
July       Project 2                          a                                16.00
                                              z                                4.00
           Project 3                          y                                1.00
```

Now, I am trying to sort this dataframe based on ``Date". In other words, I want to have June, July and September rather than having September, June, July. so here is what I am hoping to get:

```
**Date**   **Project**                     **Name**                          **Hours**
June       Project 1                          x                                1.00
                                              x                                45.00
                                              y                                6.00
July       Project 2                          a                                16.00
                                              z                                4.00
           Project 3                          y                                1.00
September  Project 1                          x                                1.00
                                              x                                3.00
           Project 2                          a                                16.00
                                              z                                4.00
           Project 3                          y                                1.00
```

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate by months and then use `rename` by dictionary:

```
MonthDict={ 1 : "January",
       2 : "February",
       3 : "March",
       4 : "April",
       5 : "May",
       6 : "June",
       7 : "July",
       8 : "August",
       9 : "September",
       10 : "October",
       11 : "November",
       12 : "December"
}

df= (df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.month, 'Project','Name'])['Hours'].sum()
       .rename(MonthDict, level=0))
```

If datetimes are sorted in original, is possible use `sort=False` in groupby for avoid sorting:

```
df= df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.strftime('%B'), 'Project','Name'], sort=False)['Hours'].sum()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you mind explaining what is happening in your code?

Comment: @BahadorSaket - Sure, in your code is by default sorting by months names in `groupby`, if sorted values on original is possible use `df= df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.strftime('%B'), 'Project','Name'] sort=False)['Hours'].sum() `